# Page won't stop loading

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, aws-amplify

Currently on an angular website deployed with amplify I have PWA activated and the starting page keeps loading up until I stop the refresh button or I click on other paths/links on the website (doesn't stop necessary stop after the first click). This is how it looks after minutes:
[image: keeps loading]

> I removed here the manifest-related things, because, in the end, the problem was just to use `crossorigin="use-credentials"` with the manifest file and this fixed the manifest error, but not the loading error.

LE: the problem is not with the manifest file, I fixed that and still the page is continuously loading. What I observed now is that now the page is using 99% of the browser CPU, which I find very strange as I can't see or find anything.

Thank you ~

Comment: Just a wild guess in the dark: Check if the file has a BOM. Use e.g. Notepad++, open the file and check under "Codecs". If it has, encode the file without a BOM and test again.

Comment: i couldn't find anything in this direction. I even converted to BOM UTF-8 and back to UTF-8 just in case.

Comment: Looking at the error I'd guess that manifest file isn't deployed to the path it's trying to be loaded from and index.html is being returned instead. Makes sure the manifest is deployed correctly and can be loaded at the correct path.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it is at the right path, currently I've checked that in Firefox and there I don't see any loading, only on chrome/brave I can see this behavior. Now I'm trying to rename the manifest file to manifest.json like here: https://web.dev/add-manifest/ to see if that will change something

Comment: Did you ever find out why your service worker was continuously refreshing the page?

Comment: Sadly I didn't find the solution yet